Wpf frame navigation automatically makes the path smaller
        public void frameNavigation(string url)
        {
            string path = "";

            if (url == "startup")
            {
                path = "Pages/Optimizations/startupManagementPage.xaml";
            }
            else if (url == "unusedM")
            {
                path = "Pages/Optimizations/unusedMemoryPage.xaml";
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                framePage.Navigate(new Uri(path, UriKind.Relative));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Navigation error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

This is a method added to my settings window. Now, as seen in the other code, I open the settings window and then call the frameNavigation method.
        private void startupAppsManagement_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            pageWindow pw = new pageWindow();
            pw.Show();
            pw.frameNavigation("startup");
        }

        private void unusedMemory_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            pageWindow pw = new pageWindow();
            pw.Show();
            pw.frameNavigation("unusedM");
        }

Normally, there seems to be no problem, but when I try to perform frame navigation, the entire path becomes smaller as if I applied the strings.lower method during the frame navigation process. Also, there is no problem with the path or url data and I am sure that I wrote the page locations correctly.
I tried many methods and finally defined a string data called path. However, it still makes the url or path smaller
Thanks in advance

I think you meant "to lower case". "Smaller" implies truncating. (And I have found no "Uri" examples that actually used mixed case. You can go through the source code).
